# Splitting time data into "runs" in order to plot and examine differences

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I am trying to investigate differences between runs/experiments in a continuously logged data set. I am taking a fixed subset of a few months for this data set and then analysising it to come up with an estimate on when a run was started. I have this sorted in a series of times.

With this I then chop the data up into 30 hour chunks (approximate time between runs) and then put it into a dictionary:

```
data = {}
for time in times:
    timeNow = np.datetime64(time.to_datetime())
    time30hr = np.datetime64(time.to_datetime())+np.timedelta64(30*60*60,'s')
    data[time] = df[timeNow:time30hr]
```

So now I have a dictionary of dataframes, indexed by by StartTime and each one contains all of my data for a run, plus some extra to ensure I have it all for every run. But to compare two runs together I need to have a common X value to stack them on top of each other. Now every run is different and the point I want to consider "the same" varies depending on what i'm looking at. For the example below I have used the largest value in that dataset to "pivot" on.

```
for time in data:
    A = data[time]
    #Find max point for value. And take the first if there is more than 1
    maxTtime = A[A['Value'] == A['Value'].max()]['DateTime'][0]
    # Now we can say we want 12 hours before and end 12 after.
    new = A[maxTtime-datetime.timedelta(0.5):maxTtime+datetime.timedelta(0.5)]
    #Stick on a new column with time from 0 point:
    new['RTime'] = new['DateTime'] - maxTtime
    #Plot values against this new time
    plot(new['RTime'],new['Value'])
```

This yields a graph like:
[image]

Which is great except I can't get a decent legend in order to tell what run was what and work out how much variation there is. I believe half my problem is because Im iterating over a dictionary of dataframes which is causing issues.

Could someone recommend how to better organise this (a dictionary of dataframes is all I could do to get it to work). I've thought of doing a hierarchical dataframe and instead of indexing it by run time, assigning a set of identifiers to the runs (The actual time is contained within the dataframes themself so I have no problem loosing the assumed starttime) and plotting it then with a legend.

My final aim is to have a dataset and methodology that means I can investigate the similarity and differences between different runs using different "pivot points" amd produce a graph of each one which I can then interrogate (or at least tell which data set is which to interrogate the data directly) but couldn;t get past various errors with creating it.

I can upload a set of the data to a csv if required but am not sure on the best place to upload it to. Thanks

Comment: The graph is not shown

Comment: Sorry I've fixed it now.

Comment: Since you will (by the sounds of it) always have a large number of runs to compare, and presumably you want to know if some particular feature is changing over time; I would suggests looking at what you can measure on each run. This will depend on what in the graph you give is important but say the fixed value of that large step, or the average value. Then plot these quantities as a function of time or a moving average.

Comment: I know the general trend that the graph should be. I'm looking for deviations from this and then trying to find reasons for them or see how they affect other things. I was more trying to ask the best way to be able to easily plot graphs like these and get them formatted easier than a dictionary of dataframes. It's just difficult to use like that.